# What's the difference between "it seems like" and "it looks like"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

Is there any difference between the two??

Comment: There's very little difference. Both refer to perception, but _look_ is more often metaphoric than visual. The version with dummy _it_ subject is due to Extraposition, but there are also [several Raising rules](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0f96/faa7842b933ab3631b080c345e84725ec2ea.pdf) that produce sentences like _Mary seems/looks like she's angry_ instead of _It seems/looks like Mary is angry._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "look" can be used to mean the same as "seem".

> look verb (SEEM)   [ L ]  to seem or appear to be:
>
> She looked like she hadn’t slept all night.

[Look (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look)